# Is there any difference between '/' and '' routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a difference between these 2 Rails routes:

```
get '/', to: 'demo#index'
```

vs.

```
get '', to: 'demo#index'
```

Both seem to match the root.

Comment: convention is to use `root  'demo#index'`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko it's just for example purposes, name it whatever you want, "cow#dog" if you want.

Comment: i meant "/" endpoint ;)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko oh, understood. My question was whether the empty string endpoint is identical to the '/' endpoint.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko @anemaria20,  They should be identical to each other. for example when you go to `https://github.com/` or `https://github.com` both are same right?

Comment: Usually it's a good practice to add '/' as when you add different views , the redirect to other pages wouldn't get messy

Comment: @Dinesh when you go to github.com, it redirects you to github.com/, '/' is supposed to be the (virtual) root directory. So they're not really the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet they are identical in all senses.

Can't provide you with any "source of truth", but there's no logical arguments I can think of to support that they are different.